# Android how to show .docx file in webview?

Tags: android

In my app i have 
URL:: http://mymobilece.com/api/api_getexammaterials.php?id=27
Its a file how to show in webview? but not with Google document viewer.

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.loadUrl("http://mymobilece.com/api/api_getexammaterials.php?id=27");
```

if it's a local file, then put it in your assets folder and do `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myFile.html");`

Comment: @Samir you've said my answer is foolish with no explanation and then downvoted. I'd like to help you out, but I think any confusion here is resulting from your poorly-worded question and poor English. I assure that writing offensive comments with no explanation will not encourage people to help you out.

Comment: your answer is simple url load in webview.Its so simple

Comment: @Samir, I don't get it. Were you looking for a more complicated answer?

Comment: Disregarding Samir's lack of online etiquette, I think the question was regarding enabling a in-app webview to support displaying *.docx files, using a plugin or such. AFAIK, WebView does not support displaying *.docx or any other document formats (not even *.pdf), even though if you attempt to open them in Google Chrome on an Android phone, they are promptly rendered.